# Remove div element before closing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a html page that runs in a panel within a program, when i click on a text field, a virtual keyboard opens via javascript thats fine. But when I close the panel in which the html page is running, the panel closes, but the virtual keyboard remains. I have tried to creade a event on focusout of the textarea but now the keybord also disappeares if i try to push a key on the keyboard.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make the keyboard disappear when I close the panel?

Here is the code:

```html
    // Add to DOM
    this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You included everything except the actual code that opens and closes the _panel_. That is where your answer lies. How ever you close/destroy/leave the _panel_ is where you'll want to remove the keyboard from view.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the code that opens the panel.

Comment: would it be possible to determine whether the body is visible? And to hide the keyboard when it is invisible?

Comment: Or would it be possible to run the keyboard like the html code so that it fades it out with the panel?
The key board may be present when opening the html.

Comment: any thing is possible, but without insight into how the moving parts work together it is nearly impossible to guess at what would work.

Answer (score 0):

I did it:

```html
      // Add to DOM
      this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
      //document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);
        document.getElementById("CustomPanel-METAR-Wrap").appendChild(this.elements.main);
```